# how to implement nested comment system using redis efficiently

Tags: database, redis

I'm trying to implement a nested comment system using redis, for example every article can have comments as first layer comments, then first layer comments can be commented and create second layer comments, and so on, can have infinite layers. Now i'm using hashs, each key represents an article, one field for article information and one field for comment, the value of comment is in xml format where tags are comment ids nested as child nodes. but it's very inefficient because each i try to retrieve the comment, i have to get all of them as a whole. So I was wondering if there's other more efficient way to do this? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a good first step is thinking about what this would look like in a relational database.  For example, a *simple* system could have the following schema:

```
Article (
  id INT,
  name TEXT,
  body TEXT
)

Comment (
  id INT,
  article_id INT,
  parent INT,
  author TEXT,
  body TEXT
)
```

Converting that to Redis takes a little thinking.  You want to make sure the data structures you use are the correct ones that provide you with the fastest look up times.  Here are the different keys/key structures I would use in implementing your system:

- `article:<id>` - a hash that stores article information and has the following keys:

  - `name` - the name of the article
  - `body` - the body text of the article
- `article-id` - an auto-increment value for the article IDs
- `article-comments:<id>` - a set of comment IDs that are top-level comments on the article whose ID is `<id>`
- `comment:<id>` - a has that stores comment information and has the following keys:

  - `author` - the comment author
  - `body` - the body text of the comment
- `comment-id` - an auto-increment value for the comment IDs
- `comment-children:<id>` - a set of comment IDs that represent comments that are replys to the comment whose ID is `<id>`

The steps for adding a new comment would be as follows:

1. Increment `comment-id`
2. Create a new hash whose key is the concatination of `comment:` and the value return in step 1
3. Fill in the hash created in step 2 with the comment data
4. If the comment does not have a parent, add its ID to the appropriate `article-comments:<id>` set.  If it does have a parent, add it to the appropriate `comment-children:<id>` set.

Comment: if i want to get the children of a certain id, i need two operations: 1.get the value of `comment-children:<id>` 2. get the `comment:<id>`, is that correct?